# Issue with an addEventListener

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I have an error when I create an addEventListener

```
inviteButton = document.querySelector(".add-invite");
  inviteButton.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    addEmail();
  });
```

./src/components/form/Invites.js
  Line 24:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

```
  22 |   };
  23 |   inviteButton = document.querySelector(".add-invite");
> 24 |   inviteButton.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
     |               ^
  25 |     addEmail();
  26 |   });
  27 |
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198403/discussion-on-question-by-m-millo-issue-with-an-addeventlistener).

Answer (score -1):

Where are you executing it? Your environment does not support ES6, Try this.

```
inviteButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    addEmail();
});
```

Comment: If it didn't support ES6, then it would error on the arrow function, not on the parts that are valid ES5.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that your querySelector returned null and didn't find your element which causes the addEventListener function not to be available.

Could you check if the class 'add-invite' is actually present on your page or post a bit more code?

Comment: If it returned `null` the error message would be something along the lines of "Cannot access property of null" not "Unexpected token"